# perl regex for printing whole statement if a single word found in statement

Tags: regex, perl

I am using perl for this

I had a long statement

```
Hi this is mounarajan from india
```

In the above statement i am writing regex for finding s/mounarajan/

if match found then it should print the entire statement "Hi this is mounarajan from india"

How to do this in perl

Answer (score 3):

```
print $statement if $statement =~ /mounarajan/;
```

You can test this as follows,

```
$ perl -e '$statement = "Hi this is mounarajan from india"; print $statement if $statement =~ /mounarajan/;'
```

[**See it live on ideone.com**](http://ideone.com/fork/Meudbv)

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
s='Hi this is mounarajan from india'
perl -ne 'print if /\bmounarajan\b/' <<< "$s"
```

Comment: `'print if /regex/'` achieves the same

Comment: @No the problem is i am crawling from website i dono where that statement lies in.i cant use any variables to identify

Comment: May be you should submit your code in question to clarify a bit more.